# Trying to setup MQ connections using SSL

Tags: ssl, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to establish MQ connection using SSL and getting below exception; I use binding file to created connection using JMS API and it looks like sslCipherSuite is not being picked from the binding file.

Below is the entry in my binding file; could you please let me know if this looks correct. Our MQ team create the binding file with JMSAdmin tool though.

```
MQD04/RefAddr/102/Type=XMSC_WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE

MQD04/RefAddr/102/Content=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

MQD04/RefAddr/102/Encoding=String
```

Exception

> ```
> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call
> failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397'
> ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').
>         at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
>         ... 27 more Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host rejected. 
> [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote
> CipherSpec error for channel 
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
>         at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
>         at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
>         at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:345)
>         ... 26 more
>
>
> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote
> CipherSpec error for channel to host ''
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment(RemoteConnection.java:4346)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH(RemoteConnection.java:3052)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1225)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:866)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
>         at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1730)
>         ... 30 more
> ```

Comment: You should look at what the queue manager's error shows.   What version and type of java are you using in the client side?

Comment: I use Java 8 and MQ 8.0.5 client jars.

Comment: Which java?  Ibm, oracle, ?  Have you checked the queue manager logs?

Comment: Oracle Java. below is the qname error message                                    
 03/29/19 09:52:43 - Process(18737.125482) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(xxx) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.10) QMgr(xxx)

AMQ9209: Connection to host 'xxxxx' for channel
'xxxx.TLS128' closed.

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred receiving data from xxxxx' over TCP/IP.
The connection to the remote host has unexpectedly terminated.

The channel name is 'x.TLS128'; in some cases it cannot be
determined and so is shown as '????

Comment: Can you please update your question by clicking edit and paste the new info into the question.   How are you  specifying to your application the location of the key store or trust store?